# Weak formulation of Stokes problem / finiding a priori estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let $\Omega$ be abounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We consider the stationary Stokes problem
\begin{cases} \Delta u + \nabla p = f  \qquad in  \ \ \ \ \Omega \\
\nabla . u =0  \qquad in \qquad \Omega \\
u =0  \quad in \qquad \partial \Omega 
\end{cases}
If we hit the problem  with a  suitable test function  $v$ and integrate by parts, we get our bilinear form
$$\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v dx = \int_{\Omega} f v  dx $$
After applying the Lax-Milgram theorem we get the existence and uniqueness, and further, we have
$$\|u\|_{H} \leq C \|f\|_{H'}$$

$H$ hilbert space, $H'$ dual of the hilbert space.
The above scenario is all good well known. Now **my question** are there any a priori estimates in the literature that relates $f$ and $u $ in a way

$$\|f\|_{\text{such  space}} \leq \|u\|_{\text{such space, preferly $\dot{H}^1(\Omega)$ }}$$
Best regards.

Comment: What's $div \ u$?

Comment: @ArcticChar it is the divergence of u (Div u) , sometimes it is written  as $( \nabla . u)$

Comment: Is $u$ a vector field?

Comment: Can you write down explicitly what is $div \ u$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I am sorry I have checked it, yes $u$ is a vector field function $u : \  \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: I think the general answer is no, the inverse is unbounded because the operator is compact.  Look at Chapter 6 of Green's Functions and Boundary Value Problems, Stakgold.  Wiley Press.  Look at the simpler problem of $-f'' = u$, given in Section 6.4.  But that doesn't mean there aren't estimates like you wrote under certain restrictions.